# Execute javascript to stop data from entering into database if validation return false

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I am using asp.net. I want to check the value of certain textboxes before entering their value in database. I tried using javascript. However it gives me an alert on checking the value but the data still gets inserted into database. Is it happening because the javascript I am using is client-side ? What's the solution for this ?

I want to perform the validation and if it fails, data shouldn't be inserted into the database.

Comment: are you checking textboxes values on submit button click ? Post your code .

Comment: Not difficult to do.  But it's very difficult for anyone to know what you're doing wrong if you don't show us the relevant code.

Comment: Remember to validate on both client and server side.

Answer (score 0):

When you validate form it submit the page.

**Use preventDefault()** OR **Return false;** function to overcome this situation.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#myForm").submit(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    //Your Validation
    if(not valid)
    {
        Return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: This may be true, and it may not.  It depends on whether the OP is submitting the page or not.  He might not be using a form at all.  We won't know until he posts his code.